# How to identify frames on webpage

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On webpage there are more than 1 frame and unable to find element on one of the frame. i am getting exception

> no such element

while searching frame

Answer (score 0):

Element is not found with its id even if its there on the web-page  reason is because its in frame
Frame is Html code but it host on the web-page as the container
Whenever we have frames selenium cannot see the frames

You need to tell the selenium there is a frame

We need to switch to frame by using

1)frame index

```
driver.switchto().frame(0);
driver.switchto().frame(1);
driver.switchto().frame(2);
```

2)frame id

If frame id is mentioned by developer you can use the frame id to switch to frame
//switch to frame and click on it

```
Driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(“iframe.demo-frame”)));
```